# Button background color not changing

Tags: python, macos, tkinter

So I'm trying to create a button with a different background color than the default of white on Mac. Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
w = root.winfo_screenwidth()
h = root.winfo_screenheight()
root.geometry("%dx%d" % (w, h))

button = tk.Button(root, text="Hello, world", fg='red', bg='black')
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

and here is the output I'm getting:

[image: Button output]

Any ideas why the background color won't change?

Comment: It works for me but in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

In many (if not most) GUI frameworks, the look&feel of widgets like buttons, radio buttons, checkboxes, list boxes, scrollbars, etc., is predefined, and cannot be changed by the program. It is so as to provide a uniform and consistent GUI experience to users.

Specific GUIs may diverge from the underlying standards by creating their own widgets.

To have a button of a non-standard color you'd have to write the code for a widget that responds to button-like events within the widget's drawing area.